# Renaming and moving files from one folder to another(windows batch)

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I'm trying to move the Files from the logs folder and move them to "C:/Application/logs" but I want to append the word "apples" to the end or beginning of each file. Is there a way to loop though the logs directory and append apples to each file? Then do the move.

Here is what I have:

```
rem "Rename the log files with apples in front"
ren logs\*.txt.*apples

rem "Move logs to backup"
move /Y logs\* C:\Application\logs\
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: which platform windows/unix/CentOS?

Comment: I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there are better ways but i belive this will work for you.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s logs\*.txt') do (
  pushd logs
  ren "%%a" "apples_%%a"
  move /y "apples_%%a" C:\Application\logs\
  popd
)
```

This batch file had to be on parent folder of your logs folder. It will find every *.txt file rename it and move it to `C:\Application\logs\` folder.